# GP Web Services - Creating Item - Won't accept item Type

Tags: c#, dynamics-gp

I'm attempting to build a form for creating items in GP and running into one issue, no matter what value I set for the item type it gets put into the database (IV00101.ITEMTYPE) as 1, which is sales inventory.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this, short of using SQL to update it after it's created, which is currently the workaround I'm leaning towards.

For reference, I'm using the CreateSalesItem(SalesItem salesItem, Context context, Policy policy) method.

Update: I've still not found anything in my own research

Comment: It does take the item type, through the salesItem parameter. Do you have some documentation saying it doesn't use it?

Also, my understanding is that the web services just calls the eConnect as sort of a wrapper, is that not accurate?

Comment: Is there really no one who has a clue on this?